# Create new scope on asp.net core project using autofac

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac

I am using aspnet core with autofac. I have two singleton services which act as cache (get data from database and cache them).I need to create a new scope so that dbcontext which is declared as InstancePerLifeTime won't be shared between the two singleton services (each service must have its own dbcontext)
How do I get the IContainer in asp.net core?
I have tried to call `containerBuild.Build();` and I get the error that container that was already build by the system.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how lifetime scopes work.

If you register something as a singleton (`SingleInstance`) it will get resolved from the root lifetime scope, not a child scope. Its dependencies _will also get resolved from the root scope (the container) and not the child scope.

[This is walked through in fair detail on the documentation topic 'Captive Dependencies'.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/captive-dependencies.html)

Basically, you can't have a singleton that takes an instance-per-request or child lifetime scope dependency. You can have a singleton that takes instance-per-dependency (which will only be resolved one time - from the container, not a child scope - and then held); or you can have a singleton that takes an instance-per-lifetime-scope component and the lifetime scope used will be the root container, effectively creating a singleton out of the thing you're consuming.

However, the question you're really asking is "how do I get the container in ASP.NET Core" and the answer to that [is also in the documentation, in the ASP.NET Core "Quick Start (Without ConfigureContainer)" section.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#quick-start-without-configurecontainer)

- Switch the `ConfigureServices` method to return `IServiceProvider` instead of `void`
- Build the container yourself and keep a reference to it somewhere of your own choosing.
- Return `new AutofacServiceProvider(container)` at the end of `ConfigureSerivces`.

There is a full code sample in the docs.

It won't help you with the larger issue, but at least you can get the container and do the experimentation you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes you are right singletons are resolved from the root scope. If I have two db repositories that are used into two singleton services it means the same repository instance (and dbcontext) will be used by both services which will cause problems because context will be shared across two services. How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: There answer is to stop making things singletons that can't be singletons. It's a design problem more than an Autofac problem.

Comment: I know singleton in most of the cases is very bad to use but unfortunately I cannot avoid it since I am building a cache based on the database and thus I need to use db repositories with unit of work

Comment: It also seems you have three answers that cover your question but the answers diverge wildly because the question is very broad. Consider taking what you got here, choosing an answer, and create a new, more targeted question that includes [a minimal, verifiable, and complete example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) It's really hard for folks to help if the question isn't entirely clear.

Comment: I have one minimal example but It is too long to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a new scope. As far as I know best practice for `dbcontext` is `dbcontext-per-business operation`. In case of web application it's a web request.

In your case you can pass some `IDbContextFactory` (singleton too) into these singletons and create new `DbContext` instance when you need it.

Comment: These services use repositories that are used also elsewhere in the system. Context factory wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve `ILifetimeScope` from a constructor and call its `BeginLifetimeScope` method.

Comment: The service must start first before anything else so I need to do it during startup.

Comment: as long as it is required by anything else, it will be created before anything else by Autofac

Comment: If you really want to get the IContainer within `Startup`, please tell me your hosting model (legacy `WebHost` or generic `Host`)

Comment: If it is WebHost, it accepts a `Startup` with a `ConfigureServices` with return value type `IServiceProvider`, then you could build your container and wrap it with `AutofacServiceProvider` from package `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and return it for ASP.NET Core to use, and that's where you can get your `IContainer` within `Startup`.

Comment: Exactly that is what I am trying to avoid. It is required by a controller and I dont want to mix their dbcontexts. WebHpst or generic Host. can you explain please?

Comment: `WebHost` is the default hosting model in ASP.NET Core 2.2 (or below), and the generic `Host` is the default one in ASP.NET Core 3.0, but they are still both avaiable in both versions. What version of template did you create the project from?

Comment: I am using .net core 2.2. I have ```public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
           
        }```

Comment: It is better not to use `ConfigureContainer` for it is a very old design, use `public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` instead.

Comment: If you want to separate the instance using of `DbContext`, you could register the DbContext as `InstancePerLifetimeScope`, and make the `AutofacServiceProvider` wrap a ILifetimeScope instead of the IContainer which is the global scope, so that ASP.NET Core services and controllers would work under a child lifetime scope

Comment: If I dont use Configure Container where do I register my types? DbContext is registered as InstancePerLifetimeScope. ```AutofacServiceProvider wrap a ILifetimeScope instead of the IContainer which is the global scope``` how do I do that?

Comment: `ConfigureServices` is the only place where it is supposed to register your service, rather than 'ConfigureContainer'.

Comment: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#quick-start-without-configurecontainer

Comment: But in order to register them using autofac I need ContainerBuilder. This does not exist on ConfigureServices. And from that link you sent the method you describe is the old one. ```This is also the path you’d take for ASP.NET Core 1.0.```

Comment: You could `new` a `ContainerBuilder`

Comment: The way you suggested is legacy.

Comment: Yeah both of them are very old and thr tutorial is there before 2.0 was released.

Comment: The new one won't be suitable for your `WebHost` hosting model, for it is to configure a generic `Host`

Comment: After all, don't use 'ConfigureContainer' unless your project is very simple without any requirements like what this question asks for, because you cannot customize the building step of container

Comment: Btw, the reason why I said it is very old is that the new generic `Host` doesn't even supports `ConfigureContainer` defined in `Startup`.